# Reduce values from a RACTuple without knowing the number of arguments of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a IBOutletCollection (TextFields). I can collect all the rac_textSignals dynamically, but now I want to reduce the values of those signals without knowing how many arguments the RacTuple will have (the outlet collection may vary).

```
NSMutableArray *signals = [@[] mutableCopy];

[self.textFields enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITextField *textField, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [signals addObject:textField.rac_textSignal];
}];
RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal combineLatest:signals];
```

How to achieve that? I can't find the way with combineLatest:reduce or reduceEach: methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RACTuple` is a collection type, so you can just enumerate over it if there are a variable number of values:

```
[[RACSignal
    combineLatest:signals]
    map:^(RACTuple *strings) {
        for (NSString *string in strings) {
            // Do whatever here.
        }

        return nil;
    }];
```

There's also an `-allObjects` method, if you'd prefer to work with an array instead.

Comment: Right, thanks! Just starting with reactive cocoa and still a bit confused with some concepts